# Reformat date from YYYY.MM.DD to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: vba, excel, date

I import a date into an Excel sheet from a text file. The date has the form: YYYY.MM.DD.

I want to reverse the date so as to be: DD/MM/YYYY.

I have tried NumberFormat, Format and some other subroutines.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ImportRange()

    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Data

    Dim Pos As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Filename = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\putty.log"

    Open Filename For Input As #1

    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not found:" & Filename, vbCritical, "ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Line Input #1, Data

    Close #1

    Pos = InStr(Data, "log")
    Sheets("ÐÉÓÔÏÐÏÉÇÔÉÊÏ").Range("B20").Value = Mid(Data, Pos + 4, 10) 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `I can also add my code if this helps someone.` - Please do, otherwise it's a bit like asking a mechanic to find out why your car doesn't work without actually taking your car.

Comment: try using `dateserial(year string, month string, day string)` in VBA

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted a sample formula for the conversion let me know if this helps.

If cell A2 has the given date you can insert the given formula in B2 
    =DATE(VALUE(LEFT(A2,4)),VALUE(MID(A2,6,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2)))

Comment: I am assuming that the date is coming up in a column A:A.  You can insert the given formula in B2 and drag it down.

Comment: Same logic can be used in VBA as well using Application.worksheetfunctions group.

Comment: Please close the question if you have got the answer to you question.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the actual cells that the dates are going in to formatted as a date